# About using left/top/right/bottom on absolute positioned textarea

Tags: html, css, firefox

I tried setting `position:absolute` and then `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` to fixed values in pixels, but unless I also set `width` and `height` I cannot get it to work properly on Firefox 11.

The rendering looks ok on safari/chrome... but is this a Firefox bug or something that isn't indeed standard? Using 100% for `width` and `height` is sometimes a solution, but not when the element is not completely covering the parent container.

See http://jsfiddle.net/EjS7v/6/

[image: Chrome, no 100% width/height] This is Chrome (and the desired result)

[image: Firefox, width/height to 100%] Firefox (width/height to 100%)

[image: Firefox, without width/height] Firefox (without width/height)

Are there alternatives to using Javascript to compute width and height at runtime?

Note that in this example I've used a fixed size div as container, but the most interesting and useful case is when the container is elastic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there's a simple alternative, use presentational markup to contain that textarea and then just 100% width height for the textarea itself.

Indeed, CSS is very limited.

Comment: Indeed the solution was trivial, I don't understand why I didn't think about it... thanks.

Comment: Well. I did it wrong so many times before I thought of that approach instead... my pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `textarea`, unlike, say, a `div`, has a [default width and height](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-textarea-element-rendering):

> If the element has a `cols` attribute, and parsing that attribute’s value using the rules for parsing non-negative integers doesn’t generate an error, then the user agent is expected to use the attribute as a presentational hint for the width property on the element, with the value being the textarea effective width (as defined below). Otherwise, the user agent is expected to act as if it had a user-agent-level style sheet rule setting the width property on the element to the textarea effective width.
>
> The **textarea effective width** of a `textarea` element is *size*×*avg* + *sbw*, where *size* is the element’s character width, *avg* is the average character width of the primary font of the element, in CSS pixels, and *sbw* is the width of a scroll bar, in CSS pixels. (The element’s letter-spacing property does not affect the result.)
>
> If the element has a `rows` attribute, and parsing that attribute’s value using the rules for parsing non-negative integers doesn’t generate an error, then the user agent is expected to use the attribute as a presentational hint for the height property on the element, with the value being the textarea effective height (as defined below). Otherwise, the user agent is expected to act as if it had a user-agent-level style sheet rule setting the height property on the element to the textarea effective height.
>
> The **textarea effective height** of a `textarea` element is the height in CSS pixels of the number of lines specified the element’s character height, plus the height of a scrollbar in CSS pixels.

Comment: Thanks... the docs seems indeed clear on that. Looks like the answer to if it's possible to avoid Javascript positioning is no :-(

Comment: And in fact, the only reason it "works" in Safari/Chrome is due to a WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81863

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: or it means that the (logical) bug is in the standard specs :-) ... I'd have expected for example some way to set `rows` and `cols` to `"auto"` or something like that. The `textarea` element seems quite broken from a design point of view (including the horrible mess about soft/hard newlines).

Comment: Oh, sure.  Lots of stuff is broken from a design point of view and can't be changed because of backwards compat problems.